# Main Taskbar (with searchbox) Showing Up on the Wrong Display

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

**(Windows 10 Pro Build 19042.685)**

The bar I am talking about is the taskbar that has the following on the leftmost side:

[image]

My main display is set to my middle monitor, and after setting the main display, it works temporarily, however, after putting my computer to sleep, turning it off/rebooting, or locking the account, the search bar will migrate to my rightmost monitor.

After this happening, the main display in Settings is still correctly set, but changing the main display, and changing it back relocated the search bar again.

I appreciate any assistance, and please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Per comments;

[image]

- A clean boot did not fix the issue
- After removing some monitor zone-ing software, the issue persists

Comment: I have multiple monitors on multiple machines, including machines I lock daily (hourly), and I have never experienced the behavior you describe.  Have you tried a simply reboot?

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, I have tried that to no success. See the end of the second paragraph, the behavior will occur *if* I turn off the computer and turn it back on.

Comment: You made no mention of trying a reboot in your question.  `Show taskbar buttons on` is set to what exactly?  Instead of replying with a comment you should edit your question. **I have fully read and comprehended your question**, I would really appreciate it, if you didn't tell me to read your question.

Comment: Is there any tools have been used to manage the multiple monitors? Please also try clean boot to verify if any non-MS tools or progress has impacted this behavior or not. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Comment: It sounds like this could be a hardware vs vendor driver vs Windows issue.  Is it possible to swap cables between your right most monitor to your middle monitor?  If so, the reconfigure the monitor setup in Windows to match it.  My line of thinking is if you connect your middle monitor to the video out port which is considered primary in the hardware sense, you may not have to worry about the software driver or Windows changing it on you.  What type(s) of video devices are you using?  There also may be settings in your motherboard firmware which declare which display is initialized first.

Comment: @Jenny Sorry for the late response, I was using PowerTools to make different zones for my monitors, but after removing that completely, the same behavior is exhibited. As for the clean boot, I performed it, and had the same issue.

Comment: @Blaelph In the hardware sense, my left-most monitor is considered primary (that is, it is where the BIOS splash posts, as well as GRUB) so I don't think it's a hardware issue- as per the comment about drivers, the hardware I'm using is an NVidia 1660ti, which is still getting driver support, and the latest driver is installed, so I am unsure if that is the issue.

Comment: @David In terms of hardware, does the location of the search bar change in this circumstance if you change the ports the monitors are using? I am wondering if one monitor is “waking” faster than the others and Windows is managing the discrepancy poorly.